# Firebase values to combobox

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, combobox

I came up with a code but nothing happens when form loads. How do I get the firebase data to a combobox? am I on the right way?

```
        {
    int i = 0;
    FirebaseResponse resp1 = await client.GetTaskAsync("Counteruser/nodeuser");
    Counter_classuser obj1 = resp1.ResultAs<Counter_classuser>();
    int cntuser = Convert.ToInt32(obj1.cntuser);

    while (true)
    {
        if (i == cntuser)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        try
        {
            FirebaseResponse resp2 = await client.GetTaskAsync("Users/" + i);
            Datausers obj2 = resp2.ResultAs<Datausers>();

            txtusername3.AddItem(obj2.Username);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your firebase database rules?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: 1) I'd be surprised if obj1.cntuser is valid. Most db readers return -1 for number of rows while reading. 2) I can't tell what UI this is. Need more to the question.